# How do you test ios apps (ipa file) in any cloud based tool like browserstack or cloud.bitbar?

Tags: ios

We are trying to test our iOS app on cloud based tools (like browserstack or cloud.bitbar), but we aren't able to start the app there. It's uploaded, started, launch the initial screen and then just crashed.

We upload it there like simple `.ipa` file exported from Xcode.

The log from one tool (cloud.bitbar, any real device type) is this:

```
Jul 11 08:34:17 CommCenter[81] <Error>: Unknown device type.
Jul 11 08:34:20 mobileactivationd(libusrtcp.dylib)[143] <Error>: tcp_output [C18.1.1:2] flags=[R.] seq=312344254, ack=1975336284, win=1027 state=CLOSED rcv_nxt=1975336284, snd_una=312344079
Jul 11 08:34:22 CommCenter[81] <Error>: Unknown device type.
Jul 11 08:34:48 apsd(libusrtcp.dylib)[99] <Error>: tcp_input [C192.1.1:2] flags=[R] seq=2075721974, ack=0, win=0 state=LAST_ACK rcv_nxt=2075721974, snd_una=3843344694
Jul 11 08:34:48 apsd(libusrtcp.dylib)[99] <Error>: tcp_input [C192.1.1:2] flags=[R] seq=2075721974, ack=0, win=0 state=CLOSED rcv_nxt=2075721974, snd_una=3843344694
Jul 11 08:34:48 timed[62] <Error>: Command 'TMSetAuthenticatedSourceTime' included mach time when not expected, forcing conversion
Jul 11 08:35:17 CommCenter[81] <Error>: Unknown device type.
Jul 11 08:35:18 com.apple.MobileInstallationHelperService(libsystem_containermanager.dylib)[154] <Error>: <private>: error = (container_error_t)<private>
Jul 11 08:35:18 appstored[128] <Error>: Cancelling maintenance operations.
Jul 11 08:35:19 mobiletimerd(MobileTimer)[49] <Error>: Connection to server via com.apple.MobileTimer.alarmserver mach port was invalidated. Removing server side connection
Jul 11 08:35:19 duetexpertd(MobileTimer)[160] <Error>: <MTXPCConnectionProvider:0x106b26eb0 com.apple.MobileTimer.alarmserver> connection invalidated
Jul 11 08:35:19 duetexpertd(MobileTimer)[160] <Error>: <MTXPCConnectionProvider:0x106b26eb0 com.apple.MobileTimer.alarmserver> not retrying invalidated connection
Jul 11 08:35:19 SpringBoard(SpotlightUI)[56] <Error>: Reply Error on 0x283382700:Connection interrupted
Jul 11 08:35:19 cloudd(CloudKitDaemon)[102] <Error>: Could not create primary backing account
Jul 11 08:35:19 syncdefaultsd[321] <Error>: BID Can't get the bundle identifier for process 229
Jul 11 08:35:19 syncdefaultsd[321] <Error>: Process with pid 229 is not authorized to access (null)
Jul 11 08:35:19 syncdefaultsd[321] <Error>: BID Can't get the bundle identifier for process 229
Jul 11 08:35:19 syncdefaultsd[321] <Error>: BID Can't get the bundle identifier for process 229
Jul 11 08:35:19 swcd[232] <Error>: Error getting enterprise-managed associated domains data. If this device is not enterprise-managed, this is normal: Error Domain=SWCErrorDomain Code=1701 "Failed to get associated domain data from ManagedConfiguration framework." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Failed to get associated domain data from ManagedConfiguration framework., Line=250, Function=<private>}
Jul 11 08:35:19 SpringBoard(SpotlightUI)[56] <Error>: Reply Error on 0x283382700:Connection interrupted
Jul 11 08:35:37 CommCenter[81] <Error>: Unknown device type.
Jul 11 08:35:38 apsd(libusrtcp.dylib)[99] <Error>: tcp_input [C194.1.1:2] flags=[R] seq=2068222971, ack=0, win=0 state=LAST_ACK rcv_nxt=2068222971, snd_una=3133512157
Jul 11 08:35:38 apsd(libusrtcp.dylib)[99] <Error>: tcp_input [C194.1.1:2] flags=[R] seq=2068222971, ack=0, win=0 state=CLOSED rcv_nxt=2068222971, snd_una=3133512157
Jul 11 08:35:38 timed[62] <Error>: Command 'TMSetAuthenticatedSourceTime' included mach time when not expected, forcing conversion
Jul 11 08:35:42 CommCenter[81] <Error>: Unknown device type.
Jul 11 08:35:42 CommCenter[81] <Error>: Unknown device type.
Jul 11 08:35:43 testmanagerd(XCTAutomationSupport)[269] <Error>: Uncaptured runtime issue reported: <private>
Jul 11 08:35:43 testmanagerd(XCTAutomationSupport)[269] <Error>: Uncaptured runtime issue reported: <private>
Jul 11 08:35:43 backboardd(CoreBrightness)[60] <Error>: invalid parameters
Jul 11 08:35:43 SpringBoard(CoreImage)[56] <Error>: -[CIImage initWithCGImage:options:] failed because the CGImage is nil.
Jul 11 08:35:43 backboardd(CoreBrightness)[60] <Error>: invalid parameters
Jul 11 08:35:43 SpringBoard(XCTAutomationSupport)[56] <Error>: Unexpectedly received animationDidStop without a matching animationDidStart. Monitoring for idle animations may no longer function correctly.
Jul 11 08:35:44 SpringBoard(XCTAutomationSupport)[56] <Error>: Unexpectedly received animationDidStop without a matching animationDidStart. Monitoring for idle animations may no longer function correctly.
Jul 11 08:35:44 CommCenter[81] <Error>: Unknown device type.
Jul 11 08:35:44 CommCenter[81] <Error>: Unknown device type.
Jul 11 08:35:44 SpringBoard(XCTAutomationSupport)[56] <Error>: Unexpectedly received animationDidStop without a matching animationDidStart. Monitoring for idle animations may no longer function correctly.
Jul 11 08:35:45 kernel(Sandbox)[0] <Error>: Sandbox: MYAPPNAME(322) deny(1) sysctl-read kern.bootargs
Jul 11 08:35:45 kernel(Sandbox)[0] <Error>: Sandbox: MYAPPNAME(322) deny(2) file-test-existence /private/etc/.mdns_debug
Jul 11 08:35:45 appstored[128] <Error>: Failed to check messages, no active account
Jul 11 08:35:47 CommCenter[81] <Error>: Unknown device type.
Jul 11 08:35:47 CommCenter[81] <Error>: Unknown device type.
Jul 11 08:35:51 kernel(Sandbox)[0] <Error>: Sandbox: bluetoothd(77) deny(1) mach-lookup com.apple.server.bluetooth
Jul 11 08:36:02 CommCenter[81] <Error>: Unknown device type.
Jul 11 08:36:03 SpringBoard(FrontBoard)[56] <Error>: [<FBApplicationProcess: 0x15d0bd4c0; application<org.MYAPPNAME.ios.dev>:322>] Provision violated for watchdog scene-create: <FBSProcessResourceProvision: 0x282870700; allowance: <; FBSProcessResourceAllowance; type: realTime; timeValue: 18.33s>; violated: YES>
Jul 11 08:36:03 runningboardd(RunningBoard)[28] <Error>: RBSStateCapture remove item called for untracked item <RBProcessMonitorObserver: 0x105718800; <RBProcess: 0x10570ecb0; 322; identity: application<org.MYAPPNAME.ios.dev>>; configCount: 0>
Jul 11 08:36:03 runningboardd(RunningBoard)[28] <Error>: Launchd says label UIKitApplication:org.MYAPPNAME.ios.dev[3cef][rb-legacy] has never exited
Jul 11 08:36:03 runningboardd(RunningBoard)[28] <Error>: Launchd says label UIKitApplication:org.MYAPPNAME.ios.dev[3cef][rb-legacy] has never exited
Jul 11 08:36:03 SpringBoard(BaseBoard)[56] <Error>: Unable to get short BSD proc info for 322: No such process
Jul 11 08:36:03 SpringBoard(XCTAutomationSupport)[56] <Error>: Unexpectedly received animationDidStop without a matching animationDidStart. Monitoring for idle animations may no longer function correctly.
Jul 11 08:36:03 SpringBoard(XCTAutomationSupport)[56] <Error>: Unexpectedly received animationDidStop without a matching animationDidStart. Monitoring for idle animations may no longer function correctly.
Jul 11 08:36:03 SpringBoard(KeyboardArbiter)[56] <Error>: HW kbd: Failed to set keyboard focus pid:0 ((null)) scene:(null)
Jul 11 08:36:03 runningboardd(RunningBoard)[28] <Error>: RBSStateCapture remove item called for untracked item 28-56-177 (target:application<org.MYAPPNAME.ios.dev>(UIScene:com.apple.frontboard.systemappservices::sceneID%3Aorg.MYAPPNAME.ios.dev-default))
Jul 11 08:36:07 CommCenter[81] <Error>: Unknown device type.
Jul 11 08:36:28 apsd(libusrtcp.dylib)[99] <Error>: tcp_input [C196.1.1:2] flags=[R] seq=1472400753, ack=0, win=0 state=LAST_ACK rcv_nxt=1472400753, snd_una=1668678907
Jul 11 08:36:28 apsd(libusrtcp.dylib)[99] <Error>: tcp_input [C196.1.1:2] flags=[R] seq=1472400753, ack=0, win=0 state=CLOSED rcv_nxt=1472400753, snd_una=1668678907
Jul 11 08:36:29 timed[62] <Error>: Command 'TMSetAuthenticatedSourceTime' included mach time when not expected, forcing conversion
Jul 11 08:36:32 CommCenter[81] <Error>: Unknown device type.
Jul 11 08:37:18 CommCenter[81] <Error>: Unknown device type.
Jul 11 08:37:19 syncdefaultsd[321] <Error>: BID Can't get the bundle identifier for process 229
Jul 11 08:37:19 apsd(libusrtcp.dylib)[99] <Error>: tcp_input [C198.1.1:2] flags=[R] seq=412524599, ack=0, win=0 state=LAST_ACK rcv_nxt=412524599, snd_una=3157974448
Jul 11 08:37:19 apsd(libusrtcp.dylib)[99] <Error>: tcp_input [C198.1.1:2] flags=[R] seq=412524599, ack=0, win=0 state=CLOSED rcv_nxt=412524599, snd_una=3157974448
Jul 11 08:37:19 timed[62] <Error>: Command 'TMSetAuthenticatedSourceTime' included mach time when not expected, forcing conversion
```

Seems like problem with signing certificates, but how to make it work?

How do you prepare your ipa files for such use case?

What's tips&tricks and good practices for this?

Comment: Your issue seems to be "unknown device type" which is not a very helpful message, as you need to choose an iOS device before you can even start running a test on BitBar.  Your best bet is probably to open a ticket with BitBar/SmartBear.  Also, I have been reading this guide which you can download from SmartBear --- https://www2.smartbear.com/bitbar-xcuitest-101-basics-best-practices.html

Comment: To follow up, here are important lessons we have learned in the process of creating an automation ready IPA for BitBar.  In the Info.plist file, the value for CFBundleSupportedPlatforms  should be set to “iPhoneOS” NOT "iPhoneSimulator" in order to run on a real device.  Also, when compiling IPA in Xcode, it must be done as "Test Build".  Other than that, the sample code that BitBar posted online for iOS should be enough to get you going.